# Max absolute value Range Sum

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming, kadanes-algorithm

I have an array `A` containing integers (positive, negative or zero). So, I want to get the maximum absolute range sum (something like `Kadane's algorithm`, but with absolute value).
For example, let A be:

`A = [-3, 2 ,-3, 1]`

so the answer there is 4 as `abs(A[0] + A[1] + A[2]) = 4.`

I tried to find the solution using Kadane's algorithm maintaining a current maximum sum, but it seems not to work in some cases. Is there a way to get the answer?

`Expected time complexity: O(n*log(n))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding minimal absolute sum of a subarray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25965939/finding-minimal-absolute-sum-of-a-subarray)

Comment: I think you can use the Kadane's algorithm to find min sum and max sum, and compare the absolute value, then return the larger one

Comment: @PetarPetrovic it worked! Thanks a lot, better than O(n*log(n))